# find and replace a word with another

Tags: replace, find

I have a file that contains either the word "Isl." (for island) or the word "Isls." (for islands) and I want to replace them with "ISLAND" and "ISLANDS" respectively in all the lines.

I use this `:%s/\<Isl.\>/ISLAND/g`  to replace the "Isl." but for some reason this command doesn't find "Isl.", but "Isls" (yes, with no dot)

Why doesn't this work as intented ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using vi editor.  The command you want is `:%s/\<Isl\./ISLAND/g` to replace Isl. to ISLAND.  Then `:%s/\<Isls\./ISLANDS/g` to replace Isls. to ISLANDS.  You can use `:help regex` for further details.

The reasons the other matches didn't work are that `\<` and `\>` match begin and end of words.  For ASCII, word characters are `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. A period can't be part of word so it'll never match anything if you do `:%s/\<Isl\.\>/ISLAND/g`.  Also `':%s/Isl./ISLAND/g'` means to match 4 letter sequence begining with Isl so it will match Isla or Islb or Islc etcetera.

The `\<Isl.\>` doesn't do what you want.  The `.` means any character and `\>` means end of word.  So it will only match 4 letter words that start with `Isl`.